# jasper reports kannada text not getting exported correctly in PDF

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to display a static text in kannada in Ireport . The Internal preview works fine but when the report is exported as PDF. the kannada text is displayed but not correctly.
I am using `Tunga` font and also setting `isPDFEmbedded =true.`

Thanks in advance